# Sort dicts from list by key - loop

Tags: python, json, database, loops, recursion

Hi i have problem with my script

```
def group_by_keys(self, key_list):
    if len(key_list) > 0:
        for headkey in key_list:
            def key_func(k):
                return k[headkey['value']]              
            data_sorted_complete = []
            for key, value in groupby(self.data, key_func):
                data_sorted_complete.append({"key_title": headkey['title'],"key": key, "values": list(value)})               
            self.grouped_data = self.grouped_data + data_sorted_complete
            del key_list[0]
            return self.group_by_keys(key_list)
    else:
        return
```

i will create a loop by `key_list` values and group my `self.data` list by this keys

That code works but not satysfying to me

**EXAMPLE KEY LIST**

```
[
    {"title": 'asd', "value":"a"},
    {"title": 'dsa', "value":"b"}
]
```

**EXAMPLE DATA**

```
[
    {
        "a": "OLZMEDD",
        "b": "13",
        "c": 'TEST1'
    },
    {
        "a": "OLZMEDD",
        "b": "13",
        "c": 'TEST2'
    },
    {
        "a": "OLZMEDD",
        "b": "13",
        "c": 'TEST3'
    },
]
```

**INCORRECT ACTUALLY RESULT**

```
[
    {
        "key_title": "asd",
        "key": "OLZMEDD",
        "values": [
            {
                "a": "OLZMEDD",
                "b": "13",
                "c": 'TEST1'
            },
            {
                "a": "OLZMEDD",
                "b": "13",
                "c": 'TEST2'
            },
            {
                "a": "OLZMEDD",
                "b": "13",
                "c": 'TEST3'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key_title": "dsa",
        "key": "13",
        "values": [
            {
                "a": "OLZMEDD",
                "b": "13",
                "c": 'TEST1'
            },
            {
                "a": "OLZMEDD",
                "b": "13",
                "c": 'TEST2'
            },
            {
                "a": "OLZMEDD",
                "b": "13",
                "c": 'TEST3'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
[
    {
        "key_title": "asd",
        "key": "OLZMEDD",
        "values": [
            {
                "key_title": "dsa",
                "key": "13",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "a": "OLZMEDD",
                        "b": "13",
                        "c": 'TEST1'
                    },
                    {
                        "a": "OLZMEDD",
                        "b": "13",
                        "c": 'TEST2'
                    },
                    {
                        "a": "OLZMEDD",
                        "b": "13",
                        "c": 'TEST3'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I will loop by first key and next loop must be inside previous loop value - as expected result

Please help me with that trouble :(

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work with the example data you've posted. e.g. it looks for `headkey['value']` but your example data doesn't contain that key.

Comment: @TomDalton key_list was added above data

Comment: Could you please explain the logic of your problem a little more? I don't understand your expected result. Why does `'dsa'` end up inside the values of `'asd'`? I think you "incorrect" results makes a lot more sense than your "expected" result.

Comment: @Stef i will create a loop by the key values, i will make grouping by specify key from list. on the example data i will group firstly by the first key "a" next grouping is by the key "b" but that next group will process inside data from "a" grouping - this must work like tree, grouping "a" next grouping "b" on grouped "a" values

Comment: for example this is my first for loop but this loop works only like parent > child, i will create loop not only for parent and child [link](https://gist.github.com/barc343/0b0a6e794e64caacb44e5d2caf1969b3) for now sorted is not required, i sort earlier in code